# Checking elements changes on page from browser extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I find the best variant of checking elements changes on page from content-script of browser extension.
For example I need add button to popup. I must check when popup will loaded and start the include.
The only method that I found is use setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [MutationObserver API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers) is what are you looking for.